# How to force Vue to destroy and re-create the component on route change?

Tags: vue.js, components, render, rerender

My routes in Vue router:

```
{ path: 'articles/create', component: () => import('Detail.vue') },
{ path: 'articles/:id/edit', component: () => import('Detail.vue') },
```

As you can see, I render the same Vue component `Detail.vue` on both routes.

How do I "force" Vue to destroy & re-create the `Detail.vue` component **when the URL changes** from for example `/articles/5/edit` to `/articles/create` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
```

Just be aware that this only forces router to destroy/create component and has no effect on router hooks - for example `beforeEnter` hook will not be called even that target component is destroyed and new one is created...